# Finding total Period length of dataset

Tags: plotting, data, data-acquisition

I've been tasked with trying to do some analysis on some data. I've been given 50000 points of data, which were claimed to have been collected at a discrete period of $1 m s$ Going under this assumption, I imported the data from a csv file which was in a `{a,b,c,d}` list format and got to work, importing data into its own `{t,data}` format list I needed and plotting it to see what I'm dealing with.

```
data = Drop[Import[file, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ","], 1];
deltav = Table[{1 10^-3 i, data[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}];
ListPlot[deltav, ImageSize -> Large, PlotStyle -> Black, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Talking to the college who asked me to have a look at it, they mentioned they took this data over a period of approx 3-4 minutes...which would be around $4\times60\times1000= 240\times10^3$ datapoints...clearly not the 50, 000 I have.

In my possibly naive assumption that the time frame of the experiment should be easily calculated at $50000\times1ms=50s$. My coworker however says the experiment was done between 240-300 seconds, and the time stamps of each saved data point was not provided, only system responses. It appears the program my college used doesn't receive the data in the correct time frame which has affected data acquisition.

The only thing I know about the data specifically, is the device was externally excited once a minute or so. Which is visibly seen each time the data crosses over 0 on the y axes, at approx 12, 22 and 40 on the x axes. With a dynamics equation of:

$\Gamma[t] = 53485.7 (0.0335 u[t] + (0.00393544 - 0.0335 u[t]) E^{(-0.134942 t)})$ with $u[t]$ being an input signal in amps.

```
\[CapitalGamma][t_] == 53485.72076313655` (E^(-0.13494168434480552` t(0.003935442899464001` - 0.33499999999999996` s[t]) + 0.335` s[t])
```

Is there a way to determine the correct time frame of the experiment (total length of the experiment in seconds, which is apparently between 240-300 seconds) with the given system dynamics and data set?

Here is a shortened 100 point dataset of the machine and its signal.

```
sdeltav = {-4.46, -3.57, -2.68, -4.46, 41.99, -14.29, -35.73, -19.65, -28.59, 
-32.16, -25.01, -33.05, -32.16, -31.27, -29.48, -17.86, -11.61, 
-15.18, -9.82, -9.82, -8.04, -8.93, -8.04, -7.14, -3.57, 47.35, 
-24.12, -23.23, 19.66, 6.26, 8.94, 4.47, 3.58, -41.99, -18.76, 
-14.29, -14.29, -14.29, -12.5, -9.82, -13.4, -8.04, -7.14, -6.25, 
2.68, 25.02, 9.83, 8.04, 9.83, 8.94, -33.05, -32.16, -22.33, -25.01, 
-23.23, -23.23, -21.44, -25.91, -32.16, -24.12, -30.37, -32.16, 
-35.73, -30.37, -25.01, -30.37, -25.01, -23.23, -25.91, -24.12, 
-21.44, -24.12, -24.12, -7.14, -10.72, -11.61, -6.25, 0.9, -19.65, 
40.2, -85.76, 46.46, 4.47, -19.65, -1.78, 5.36, 25.02, 8.94, 9.83, 
10.72, 6.26, 8.04, 8.04, -25.01, -16.08, -10.72, -8.04, 480.64,
592.31, 611.07}


sudata = {-0.14, -0.03, -0.13, -0.01, 0.18, -0.28, -0.03, -0.05, -0.09, 0.04, 
-0.04, -0.01, -0.04, -0.07, -0.03, -0.04, -0.15, -0.04, -0.02, -0.02, 
-0.17, -0.01, -0.05, -0.12, -0.06, 0.1, -0.1, 0.15, 0.08, 0.05, 0.15, 
0.17, 0.01, 0.04, -0.05, -0.14, -0.07, -0.1, -0.1, -0.11, -0.03, 
-0.11, -0.01, 0.05, 0.21, 0.12, 0.14, 0.1, 0.12, 0.18, -0.33, -0.09, 
-0.12, -0.15, -0.03, -0.04, 0.03, -0.03, 0.01, -0.14, -0.19, -0.02, 
0.01, -0.01, -0.08, 0.08, -0.15, -0.14, -0.03, -0.05, -0.16, -0.09, 
-0.02, -0.02, -0.03, -0.11, -0.05, 0.16, -0.18, 0.1, 0.14, -0.07, 
0.11, -0.03, -0.19, 0.24, 0.03, 0.15, -0.05, -0.03, 0.12, 0.04, 0.11, 
-0.15, -0.06, -0.13, -0.08, 6.2, 5.94, 6.01}
```

The original data sets are at pastebin.

[deltav](https://pastebin.com/2D4DTVev) and [udata](https://pastebin.com/QfWkitiM)

Comment: I think your description is not that clear on what you want and brings further questions. Is it correct that the data is missing time-stamps of the monitored value? Do you want to verify that the data is taken over a regular time grid? Or you are sure that that is the case? Do you want to get a "goodness of fit" estimate is the data representing device's monitored variable over a regular time grid with step 1ms? (Etc.)

Comment: Also, of course, is it possible for you the share the full data?

Comment: In order for me to work on the data, I need to know the length of the experiment the data was acquired. Since each data point was (supposed to be) saved once every millisecond, my assumption was the experiment lasted 50 seconds. My coworker says the experiment was between 240-300 seconds. However this was not saved within the dataset given to me and am unable to verify the *actual* period of the experiment and thusly not further analyse the dataset. I do not intend to fit the data and want to use this data for an interpolation function but I need the real accurate experiment duration.

Comment: ahh it's 50000 points. I can gladly give it...but I think posting 100, 000 points here would be a bit too much..can I post it somewhere else, pastebin?

Comment: @AntonAntonov I tried to clean up the post, thanks for the suggestion. I hope its clearer now.

Comment: Yes, pastebin or something similar would work.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I have added the original data sets.